# Export an excel file using a variable name in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am new to python, trying to figure out dynamic naming of exported files. Right now, I am exporting an xlsx file in a traditional way:

data_subset.to_csv('Destination/existing_process.csv')

I have a string called 'user_name' and the resultant tuple for every user is exported into an excel file called existing_process. Instead of the name existing_process, I would like to rename the file dynamically using the string user_name.

For instance, for a given user_name 'Matt' I would like the exported file to be named as Matt.csv. Thanks!

Comment: and what exactly is the issue you're facing? Writing the excel file and providing the filename as `user_name` won't suffice? Instead of simply stating a requirement, make sure you add existing attempts at doing this and what isn't working.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `string concatenation` for that.

```
name = 'Matt'
with open(name + '.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('test')
```

The same you can use with `xlsx` but you will you using it slightly different, but the concatenation process is same. Kindly let me know if you want the exact procedure with `xlsx`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
inv.name = 'Rem_inv'

dataframe_list = [inv]
for dataframe in dataframe_list:
    dataframe.to_csv(df.name + '.csv')
```